# Match @(\w+) and replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match @(\w+) in a div content and remove it.

Here's what i've tried : http://jsfiddle.net/mxgde6m7/1/ .

@(\w+) works , but it doesn't replace with space.

```
var content = document.getElementById('contentbox');
    var find = '@(\w+)';
    var reg = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    var result = content.innerHTML.replace(reg, ' ');
    alert(result);

<div id="contentbox">@d <a href="#" id="5">test </a>
```

What i want: `<div id="contentbox"><a href="#" id="5">test </a>
</div>`

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Okay,  one problem solved, another one came up.
My script http://jsfiddle.net/mxgde6m7/9/ works perfectly there, but when i try it on my website, only a half works. The last part where it should replace @(\w+) with space doesn't work at all. If i copy/paste the CONTENT of the function in console(chrome), it works , but if i paste the function and i call it, it doesn't work.

Please help ! I'm stuck.

Comment: You can also use a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) so a string isn't involved -- `var reg = /@(\w+)/g;`

Answer (score 1):

Using a RegExp constructor, you need two backslashes `\\` in place of each backslash `\`.

```
var find = '@(\\w+)';
```

Answer (score 0):

[hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd) is correct that you need to double escape \w in your regular expression.

```
var find = '@(\\w+)';
```

But, you could also make this code much cleaner by defining a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) like so -

```
var content = document.getElementById('contentbox');
var result = content.innerHTML.replace(/@(\w+)/g, ' ');
alert(result);
```

Doing it this way doesn't require double escaping, as it's not a string.